# How do I keep only records that have letters in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

I have an array that I am looking to validate, specifically names from a list of contacts. Some of the object in this array are missing names and instead have phone numbers in that property. How do I filter out any records where the name property is not made of letters? (name only ever have letters). So in the example below I should be left with only one record (Carl Johnson) since that one has a full name.

**MY DATA**

```
let arrayIn=  [
    {phoneNumbers:[
        { label: 'work',  number: '+3476859087'},
        { label: 'mobile', number: '+4567893214'}
        ],
        lookupKey:"12345",
        company:"PHONE",firstName:"",contactType:"person",name:"71892823",id:"879",
        emails:[
            {email:'johnSmith@gmail.com'}
        ],
        lastName:"Smith",
    },
    {phoneNumbers:[
        { label: 'mobile', number: '+3476859087'},
        { label: 'work', number: '+4567773214'}
        ],
        lookupKey:"890744",
        company:"PHONE",firstName:"Carl",name:"Carl Johnson",id:"879",
        emails:[
            {email:'cjohnsonh@gmail.com'}
        ],
        lastName:"",
    }
    ]

fetchContacts = async () => {
  console.log('fetching contacts')
    let { status } = await Permissions.getAsync(Permissions.CONTACTS);
    if (status !== Permissions.PermissionStatus.GRANTED) {
      // TODO: Handle permissions denied.
      console.log('permissions have been denied')
      await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CONTACTS);
    } else {
      console.log('permission granted')

      //pull data from contacts          
      //const { data } = await Contacts.getContactsAsync({
      //fields: [Contacts.Fields.Emails],
      //});

      const { data } = await getContactsAsync({
        fields: [EMAILS, PHONE_NUMBERS],
      });

      if (data.length > 0) {
        const contact = data.reduce((acc, {
          id,
          name,
          phoneNumbers,
          emails
          }) => {
            return [...acc, {
              'id': name,
              'name': name ? name : null,
              'phone': phoneNumbers ?  this.validatePhone(phoneNumbers[0]['number']) : null,
              'email': emails ?  emails[0].email : null
              }];
          }, []);
        this.setState({ contacts: contact.slice(10,15).filter(c=>c.name!=(HERE IS WHERE I WOULD FILTER OUT ANY NAMES THAT HAVE NUMBERS)) })

      }
    }
};
```

Comment: An easier approach would be to check if the name is not made of numbers.

Comment: I may have articulated the question incorrectly. That is what I mean, how do I check to see if name has numbers in it and therefore filter it out?

Comment: I've posted an answer below ▼

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that a name is invalid whenever it contains a digit, you can use regex for finding a digit in the string.

```
const contacts = [
    {
        name:"71892823"
    },
    {
        name:"CarlJohnson"
    },
    {
        name:"Carl Johnson"
    },
    {
        name:"Carl124"
    },
    {
        name:"Carl124 Johnson"
    }
];

const res = contacts.filter(person => !(/\d/.test(person.name)))

console.log(res)
```

Output

```
[ { name: 'CarlJohnson' }, { name: 'Carl Johnson' } ]
```

Answer (score 2):

An easier approach would be to check if the name is not made of numbers. You can use `!Number()` or `isNaN()`, along with `.filter()` to filter if the `name` is a number or not.

```js
let arrayIn=  [
    {
     phoneNumbers:[
            { label: 'work',  number: '+3476859087'},
            { label: 'mobile', number: '+4567893214'}
        ],
     lookupKey:"12345",
     company:"PHONE",
     firstName:"",
     contactType:"person",
     name:"71892823",
     id:"879",
     emails:[
         {email:'johnSmith@gmail.com'}
     ],
     lastName:"Smith",
    },
    {
     phoneNumbers:[
        { label: 'mobile', number: '+3476859087'},
        { label: 'work', number: '+4567773214'}
     ],
     lookupKey:"890744",
     company:"PHONE",
     firstName:"Carl",
     name:"Carl Johnson",
     id:"879",
     emails:[
       {email:'cjohnsonh@gmail.com'}
     ],
     lastName:"",
    }
];
let arrayOut = arrayIn.filter(val => !Number(val.name));

console.log(arrayOut);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `isNaN()` and `filter()` functions:

```js
const contacts = [{phoneNumbers:[{label:'work',number:'+3476859087'},{label:'mobile',number:'+4567893214'}],lookupKey:"12345",company:"PHONE",firstName:"",contactType:"person",name:"71892823",id:"879",emails:[{email:'johnSmith@gmail.com'}],lastName:"Smith",},{phoneNumbers:[{label:'mobile',number:'+3476859087'},{label:'work',number:'+4567773214'}],lookupKey:"890744",company:"PHONE",firstName:"Carl",name:"CarlJohnson",id:"879",emails:[{email:'cjohnsonh@gmail.com'}],lastName:"",}]

const res = contacts.filter(person => isNaN(person.name))

console.log(res[0].name)
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may just use `match` function,it searches for matches on given string. If it will finds any matches,it will return an array with all matches otherwise it will return `null`

```
filter(c => !c.name.match(/[0-9]/gi))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just finish it with RegEx

```js
var data = [
    {phoneNumbers:[
        { label: 'work',  number: '+3476859087'},
        { label: 'mobile', number: '+4567893214'}
        ],
        lookupKey:"12345",
        company:"PHONE",firstName:"",contactType:"person",name:"71892823",id:"879",
        emails:[
            {email:'johnSmith@gmail.com'}
        ],
        lastName:"Smith",
    },
    {phoneNumbers:[
        { label: 'mobile', number: '+3476859087'},
        { label: 'work', number: '+4567773214'}
        ],
        lookupKey:"890744",
        company:"PHONE",firstName:"Carl",name:"Carl Johnson",id:"879",
        emails:[
            {email:'cjohnsonh@gmail.com'}
        ],
        lastName:"",
    }
    ];
    
    console.log(data.filter((data)=>!(/\d/.test(data.name))))
```